# Sizing bootstrap capacitor for Power Mosfet driver chip

Tags: capacitor, mosfet-driver

I read some questions on this form regarding bootstrap capacitor e.g.:
[Bootstrap capacitor - Explanation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338838/bootstrap-capacitor-explanation)
and this
[Boost capacitor sizing, gate driver LM5106 used with N-MOSFET IPP075N15N3 G](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224004/boost-capacitor-sizing-gate-driver-lm5106-used-with-n-mosfet-ipp075n15n3-g)

the second one is a bit helpful but they are basing the cap size based on Qg but not showing any calculations. The mosfet I am using is **IRF1405** and datasheet shows Qg:
[image]

The driver I am using is **HIP4081**. I read the [application notes](https://www.renesas.com/cn/en/www/doc/application-note/an9405.pdf) for the driver and on page 6 has a formula for Cbootstrap:
[image]

and at the end the formula boils down to this (we can ignore the marked term):
[image]

assuming bootstrap cap voltage difference is 1 `**QRR** = 12.5nC. Then QBS = 260 + 12.5 =  272.5nC or 0.27uC.`

should I go with 0.33 uC or 0.22 uC?

Comment: On the first look, I think the cap is way to small.

Comment: would it be then safe to say that the cap should be >= 10 x Qg? which would give me 2.6uC.

Comment: Wait a minute, I can see now. You are searching a cap with Coulomb rating? There is no such. Coulomb is a unit of charge, Farads are capacitance units.